onchange event do not enter to a break point on select tag in Blazor .NET 8
I am trying to debug the OnSelectChanged function. When I select an option, the execution does not hit the breakpoint I set on the line Opcion = opcion; within the OnSelectChanged function.
However, breakpoints in other functions are working correctly. Does anyone know how I can fix this?
I am using Blazor and .NET 8.
.razor file:
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 p-3">
        <select id="dropdown1" class="form-select" @onchange="@(e => OnSelectChanged(true, e.Value.ToString()))">
            <option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>
            <!-- Organizacion -->
            @if (Opcion == "Organizacion")
            {
            }
            <!-- Niveles Web -->
            else if (Opcion != "Organizacion" && ListaCategoriasNivel1.Count > 0)
            {
                @foreach (var categoria in ListaCategoriasNivel1)
                {
                <option value="@categoria.CodigoNivel">@categoria.NombreNivel</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

.razor.cs file:
private void OnSelectChanged(bool status, string opcion)
{
    Opcion = opcion;
}

I tried to create another function to see if it hits the breakpoint and that did not work either.

Blazor has a bunch of built-in input components. There is InputSelect<TValue>, which wraps HTML's select. Have you tried it? Is there any reason to implement the same by yourself? See also this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms/input-components?view=aspnetcore-9.0#input-components and this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-9.0

Please try InteractiveServer render mode.
.razor:
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer //Add this line
    
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 p-3">
        <select id="dropdown1" class="form-select" @onchange="@(e => OnSelectChanged(true, e.Value.ToString()))">
            <option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>
            <!-- Organizacion -->
            @if (Opcion == "Organizacion")
            {
            }
            <!-- Niveles Web -->
            else if (Opcion != "Organizacion" && ListaCategoriasNivel1.Count > 0)
            {
            @foreach (var categoria in ListaCategoriasNivel1)
            {
                <option value="@categoria.CodigoNivel">@categoria.NombreNivel</option>
            }
            }
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

.razor.cs:
public partial class Home
{
    private string Opcion;
    private List<Categoria> ListaCategoriasNivel1 = 
    [
        new() { CodigoNivel = "1", NombreNivel = "0001" },
        new() { CodigoNivel = "2", NombreNivel = "0002" },
        new() { CodigoNivel = "3", NombreNivel = "0003" }
    ];
    private void OnSelectChanged(bool status, string opcion)
    {
        Opcion = opcion;
    }
}

public class Categoria
{
    public string CodigoNivel { get; set; }
    public string NombreNivel { get; set; }
}

